# How do you modify the contents of an HTML table row based on the contents of another cell in the row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following table:

[image]

How can I modify columns 2 and 3 if the contents of column 1 satisfy a condition?  I want to be able to say "for all rows, if column 1 == 37, set column 2 to 12:00:00".

Comment: I've figured out how to select the desired row to modify.  I achieved my goal by grabbing the entire innerhtml of the row and modifying the string.  However, this approach is messy and I was wondering if there was a cleaner and more efficient way to do it (jquery, perhaps?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you appear not to have used jquery much, to keep it simple, you can use

```
$("table tr").each
```

to loop through each table row. If your table has an ID, then better:

```
$("#tableid tr").each
```

in each row, check if the first cell is 37 and then set the 2nd to the value you want.

```js
$("table tr").each(function() {
  var cells = $("td", this)
  if ($(cells[0]).text() == "37") $(cells[1]).text("12:00");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, you can do it like this

```js
$("#my-table tr").each(function () {
  if($(this).find('td:eq(0)').text() === '37'){
    $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text('12:00:00');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="2" id="my-table">
   <tr>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>02:28:17</td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>74</td>
      <td>13:56:21</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```